# Loading WebSite (developed with WebRTC) in WebView in Xamarin not loading Camera

Tags: xamarin, webrtc

I'm building an application using WebRTC and where I load Website in a Xamarin Webview.

On Website I open device camera ( take pics etc ) and its working perfectly fine on all browsers, But when I load same application in Xamarin Webview then mobile camera doesn't show up. Any idea what could be the reason ?

I need best possible approach to do Video chat application on Mobile.

please provide me suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Sukesh.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [WebRTC native](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/) libraries for Xamarin. If you are good with using precompiled libraries then you may find it over web. However I would suggest to compile webrtc native for each target platform you want. It is not that easy job , it will take time to compile and integrate it. I was working with team which was working on the same but not using Xamarin. They took lots of time to understand and implement this. Once you have libraries ready for your platform then you can use it with xamarin.

There some library available.

1. Icelink (may be paid license is needed). You can check in detail [here](https://components.xamarin.com/view/icelinkcommunity).
2. Sample of Icelink (you can find how to implement). Check [this](https://github.com/SuavePirate/Xamarin.WebRTC).
3. Video chat app using [Vidyo.io](https://vidyo.io/blog/how-to/vidyo-io-xamarin/) for xamarin.
4. Article on WebRTC using Xamarin. Check [this](http://kenneththorman.blogspot.my/2014/01/webrtc-app-c-xamarin-part-1-building.html).

Hope this will boost your work. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response.  I have already implemented WebSite using (WebRTC) and hosted on Microsoft Azure  URL Link http://sukeshwebrtc.azurewebsites.net/index.html   , but when I load this URL in Webview of Xamarin is not opening Mobile Camera...!!   please suggest - if you have any information to resolve issue.

Comment: You are welcome Sukesh. upvote or mark as answer if it is helpful to you. And also put comments if more help is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response.  I have already implemented WebSite using (WebRTC) and hosted on Microsoft Azure  URL Link http://sukeshwebrtc.azurewebsites.net/index.html   , but when I load this URL in Webview of Xamarin is not opening Mobile Camera...!!   please suggest - if you have any information to resolve issue.

Comment: You code does not work only laptop and its giving error for not accessing web cam. I suggest you check the connector class or plug in or the code which is responsible for accessing hardware on any device. As you mobile platforms have different way of accessing than the web one.

Comment: My code will work only in Firefox browser, since getUserMedia() error on chrome browser.  Please check in Firefox browser for now. Thanks.

Comment: chrome requires https for getUserMedia access.

Comment: Yes with Https it is working fine in Chrome browser but not in WebView of Xamarin.  Please help me to load Camera from WebView.